# if command checking between multiple varible not working Javascript

Tags: javascript

hi I have this code that is supposed to choose between multiple different different variable to check the answer this is the code

```
function handler(evt) {
  if (document.getElementById("answer").value == (result,result1,result2,result3)) {
    correct++
    document.getElementById('f').innerHTML =("correct!")
    document.getElementById('answer').value = ''
```

What I want it to do is check between all of the varables `result,reulst1,result2,result3` I have tried a lot but I will not work. For the full code go to this link [This](https://replit.com/join/rspeslknxt-somone14yt)

thanks

Comment: Check each one individually using an or `||` or make an array and use `.includes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with || or statement

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
 if (answer == result || answer == result1 || answer == result2 || answer == result3)) {
 correct++
}
```

another option is to add all your results to array:

```
var results = [result, result1, result2, result];
```

and to check if the value include in the array:

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
results.includes(answer);
```

good luck